# Angular dynamically insert HTML that contains cdkDropListGroup, cdkDropList, and cdkDrag so that the cdkDrag items are draggable

Tags: html, angular, dynamic, insert, draggable

I need to insert HTML that is created by the user of the application.
The HTML has several "sections" where content can be dragged into those "sections".
This is an example of the HTML that the user can create:

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
    <div cdkDropList>
        <div cdkDrag>
            item #1
        </div>
        <div cdkDrag>
            item #2
        </div>
        <div cdkDrag>
            item #3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have attempted to do this using a Directive, ViewChild, Injectable, but nothing seems to be getting close to solving the problem. Is this even possible in Angular?  Could someone direct me towards a method that should work?

Comment: How is it ‘created by the user’ exactly?

Comment: The user uploads a HTML file containing the Example that I posted.